# Django - Rendering unicode characters in templates correctly

Tags: python, django, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

I get a string from database: Camiña
But the template render this: CamiÃ±a
If print type(s) I get: 'unicode'
If print sys.getdefaultencoding() I get: UTF-8

I don't know how to get the correct print, I've tried to encode, decode, but always get CamiÃ±a. :(

Encoding is very confusing to me.

Comment: is the browser set to utf8?

Comment: Yes. Rendering is wrong in browser and stdout.

Comment: Are you using mysql? Is there any extra db settings?

Comment: Oh.. my database was in latin1, I used encode('latin1') in my view and I got the correct string! :') Thanks.